# What is the phonological process whereby a speaker uses [ʊ] as a replacement for [l]?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, vowels, consonants, articulation

What is the phonological process whereby a speaker would use [ʊ] as a replacement for [l]?

Some examples off the top of my head; [lɪtl] -> [lɪtʊ], [gɪgl] -> [gɪgʊ], [twɪŋkl] -> [twɪŋkʊ]

Comment: In English this is a progression from ["dark l"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_lateral_approximant#Voiced_velarized_alveolar_lateral_approximant).

Comment: Perhaps laziness to open your mouth ;D?

Comment: Is this for English? I've never heard this at all? Is this ... 'baby' talk?

Comment: Phonologists call this [l-vocalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-vocalization).

Comment: @Mitch: It was very common in Australian English when I was growing up, and I think it still is. I remember one host of the TV chat show *Beauty and the Beast* making fun of it at every opportunity.

Comment: @hippietrail: It's good to know that this is common in a variant of English and you've specified it. Hopefully others will chime in noting which other varieties this occurs in (and confirm or disconfirm what I hear). Maybe also try it on ELU?

Comment: I can confirm that this is EVERYWHERE in Australia. I use it frequently, however a lot of people stigmatise it, especially when it's obvious. (It's more obvious to us when it's simply syllable final, and not a syllabic consonant).

So as a result, most people say, for example, "girl" with a dark l, but some don't. However I can claim that the majority will say a word, like "twinkle", with [ʊ] and not a dark l.

Answer (score 2):

I say this a lot. Like Hippietrail said, it's a progression from the dark l.
I can say  as [wɫ̩] when it's used as a discourse particle. My dialect tends to turn a syllable final velarized [ɫ] into [w]. As a result, I VERY often say [wː] instead of [wɛɫ]. I can record it if you like.

That aside, the way it progresses from a dark l to a [w] or a [ʊ], depending on your perspective (is it a syllabic consonant, or a vowel? lol) is because the mouth shape for [ɫ] is almost exactly the same for [w] except the apex of the tongue is touching the alveolar ridge. As soon as the tip lets go, it sounds like [w] and not [ɫ].

In case you don't know, [ɫ] is an /l/ with the back of the tongue velarized. That is, it's nearing the velum (where you produce /k/ and /g/).

As for the name of this phonological process? I haven't the faintest idea. De-alveolarisation, maybe? Haha, maybe not.

Comment: Probly "velarization" is still the important term. The laterality isn't needed finally, as long as the velar nature can be determined. [ʊ] is the ideal vowel to represent dark /l/, since it's velar (i.e, high back, just as high front is palatal) and lax (and thus not very strongly rounded or diphthongized).

Answer (score 2):

It's basically a type of [debuccalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debuccalization). Although the standard examples of debuccalization are things like *s > h* and *t > ʔ*, this is the same kind of process, since the loss of alveolar closure turns syllabic [ɫ] into a kind of laterally colored high back vowel.